# Trying to generate executable .jar file

Tags: java, class, export

I know this has been asked before, but I can not find an answer and it is getting a bit tedious. I have tried using eclipse to export it, and also using cmd to generate it myself, but I always get an error when trying to run. "Invalid header field" or "could not find or load main class". What I am trying to do is link a Java program, and a separate file for the class. "ScreenRobotProgram.java" and "ScreenRobot.class". These are both in the package "ScreenRobot". So, how can I link these to an executable Java program? Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Okay Acewin, but as I said in my original question, these methods don't work (I have done them correctly, multiple times) and I just get error codes when I try and run the program.

Comment: then you should post the method you are following and the error you have been getting rather than ask question how to generate executable jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to learn what GOOGLE is

All possible ways to generate executable

[Generate Java executable through Java commands](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/)

[Generate Java executable through ant](https://ideoplex.com/2008/10/05/building-an-executable-jar-with-ant/)

[Generating Executable Jar in Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)

[Generate Java executable through Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/) OR [Create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)